# Why can't I return the Golden Claw?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cleared Bleak Falls Barrow, got the shout as well as the Dragonstone, and returned it to Farengar.

However, I'm not getting an option to return the Claw to Lucan. Nor is the Dragon Rising quest starting. Why would this be?

Comment: Is the claw still in your inventory?

Comment: Are you using any mods on your game?

Comment: The claw has nothing to do with the Dragon Rising quest so no worries there. If Farengar accepted the stone you should have been interrupted in a conversation with him to continue on that quest line. Its possible they are just waiting for you up the stairs behind the Jarl's throne.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you can return the claw to either Lucan *or* Camilla (through conversation cues), which will complete the quest.

If you are on PC, you can use console commands to complete the quest, changing the attributes of the Golden Claw to no longer quest-related, meaning you can drop, or sell the claw.

As for the Dragon Rising quest, Jarl Balgruuf will interrupt a conversation with you and Farengar, and then will wait for you to talk to him at the top of the stairs, behind the Jarl's throne, as James pointed out. If this doesn't happen, leave the building, wait a few in-game hours, then re-enter and make your way up behind the throne, and talk to Balgruuf then.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have the claw, if so did you talk to them when they were in the store, if no, they won't give the option as I found out until morning when in the store. If yes, this is a bug, waiting helps. And for dragon rising reload any saves or wait a few hours until irealeth calls you.

Comment: Why dislike? This is a good option!